# wget - How to create local subdirectories when using ‘-P prefix’ ‘--directory-prefix=prefix’?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, macos

I have added `--directory-prefix=~/Downloads` in `~/.wgetrc`

Looking through the [manual for wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) I am having trouble understanding how to pass a local subdirectory on the command line that would **amend** the directory prefix path that is set in `.wgetrc`.

*I presume I can bypass by declaring a new `--directory-prefix` in the call, but I am asking can the call be amended without having to.*

**pseudocode**

```
wget ./subdirectory https://www.website.com
```

Presuming that "." would represent the `--directory-prefix` set in .wgetrc

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
wget $(grep directory-prefix ~/.wgetrc)/subdirectory https://www.example.com
```

would work (it obviously will fail if `directory-prefix` isn't set).

PS: Not sure it is all that useful, though :-)

Comment: Not a terrible option - I suppose I could build a function. I was looking for a method built into `wget` itself and thought I may have overlooked some flag or option... I guess when they refer to "subdirectories" they aren't talking about local directories but the directories created when downloading a website.